# How to read/parse article content from link to string

Tags: java, android

I was in need of help.
How do I get content on article websites with java or android?

Answer (score 2):

You can try http://jsoup.org/

Use it to fetch the page from link and parse the content.

Well, here is a sample,

```
String url = "http://inet.detik.com/read/2012/12/12/105558/2116258/796/produktif-kerja-mobile-dengan-samsung-ativ-smart-pc-yang-revolusioner";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(20000).get();
Elements elements = doc.select("div[class=text_detail]");
if (elements.size() > 0) {
    System.out.println(elements.text());
}
```

The above code just print outs the entire text. If you want to get a pretty print version, you need to handle some html tags (such as br) by yourself. You can easily visit the html tags with jsoup, so just spend some time on the documents and write the code on your own.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, i have use library jdom, whether it can use jdom?

Comment: jdom is good for parsing xml, but web pages normally have dirty html tags, so in my opinoin, using jdom is not suitable.

Comment: Just provide a simple example. You need do more to complete your requirement.

Comment: You should analyse the logcat output, there should be some error messages or stacktrace.

Comment: I get error in here, where i look at via logcat:  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:393)

Comment: The tutorial your posted has errors. You can not invoke http connection in main thread. You need to run the jsoup code in seperate thead or in AsyncTask